# Get all members for groups and subgroups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adgroup

good day to all.
I've been trying to get information about groups and subgroups in Active Directory
I've tried many variants like the one below,

What I essentially need is, to get a CSV of all the groups in AD that contain "infolink" in their name, and the columns I need are:

- GiveName
- SN
- Username
- Mail
- Group
- ManagedBy

But no matter how I put it I only get some of the things I need.
Does someone already have a bit of code that could make my life a bit easier? If so, I'd be immensely grateful.

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $Groups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "*Infolink*"} |         select name -ExpandProperty name)

    $Table = @()

    $Record = @{
      "Group Name" = ""
      "Name" = ""
      "Username" = ""
      "mail" = ""
    }


    Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {

      $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group -recursive |         select name,samaccountname

      foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
        $Record."Group Name" = $Group
        $Record."Name" = $Member.name
        $Record."UserName" = $Member.samaccountname
        $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
        $Table += $objrecord

      }
    }

    $Table | export-csv "D:\Infolink.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: use the `SamAccountName` to look them up with `Get-ADUser`. You will get more infos than with `Get-ADGroupMember`

Comment: Could you please show me how that would go in that peace of code? I'm quite new to this  $Arrayofmembers = Get-SamAccountName -identity $Group -recursive |

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*Infolink*'" -Properties ManagedBy
$table = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive
    $ArrayofmembersUsers = $Arrayofmembers | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail
    $ArrayofmembersUsers | Add-Member -Name GroupInfoLinkName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $group.Name -Force
    $ArrayofmembersUsers | Add-Member -Name GroupInfoLinkManageBy -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $group.ManagedBy -Force
    $ArrayofmembersUsers
}
$table | Select-Object -Property GivenName, SurName, SamAccountName, Mail, GroupInfoLinkName, GroupInfoLinkManageBy | Export-Csv "D:\Infolink.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Some Pointers..

- Use the Filter on `Get-ADGroup` else you're getting all groups in AD and then filtering.
- PSObject are great but if your Object already has the majority of the properties you require then `Add-Member` is helpful to add 1 or 2 more.
- Many cmdlets have a Properties parameter, you'll see I've used this to include properties that were not included by default. Unfortunately `Get-ADGroupMember` is not one of those cmdlets so piping to `Get-ADUser` helps provide a workaround.